# Export CSS-styled HTML to PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I am applying for a job and need a resume. Because I really hate working with Word and it drives me nuts using it for such a purpose I just did it with HTML and CSS, thinking it would be fairly easy to export it to pdf later.

But well, it turned out to be harder than expected. I have tried using jsPDF and pretty much every method decribed in posts on stackoverflow regarding this subject, but it somehow was always distorted or did not work at all.
Either there was no css included or there was only a part of my resume in the pdf.

I have attached the files and need the `.page` to be exported as pdf, the format should be A4 already.

Is there a way to achieve what I need using JavaScript/jQuery ?
In the worst case scenario it would also be possible for me to use php, but that would make things way more complicated for me.

I know it probably would be easiest to just do it in Word or something like that regarding time consumption. But just from personal interest how would I have to do it ?

Thank you guys very much in advance

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

body {
 background:#aaa;
}

.dash {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 1px;
 background: #676767;
 display: block;
 clear:both;
}

.page {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 1414.2135px;
 background: white;
 margin: 100px auto;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.page .overlay #left_rect {
 width: 200%;
 height: 500px;
 background: #676767;
 position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    left: -100%;
 top: -50px;
}

.page .overlay #right_rect {
 width: 200%;
 height: 500px;
 background: #26556d;
 position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(16.18deg);
    z-index: 2;
    left: -100px;
    top: -249px;
}

.page .left,
.page .right {
 float: left;
}
.page .left {
 width: calc(38.1966% - 50px);
 height: 100%;
 background: #eee;
 padding: 565px 25px 0;
}

.page .left img {
 width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    top: 190px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.page .left .section {
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.page .left .section.contact {
 position: absolute;
 left: 25px;
 bottom: 0;
}

.page .right {
 width: calc( 61.8034% - 50px);
 height: 100%;
 margin-top: 200px;
 padding: 25px;
}

.page .right .top h1 {
 color: #255571;
 font-size: 35px;
 float:left;
}

.page .right .top h2 {
 color: #666;
 font-size: 20px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.page .right .top:after {
 content:'';
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 height: 25px;
}

.page .right .section:after {
 content:'';
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 height: 25px;
}


.page .section h1 {
 color: #26556d;
 font-size: 25px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.page .right .section .sub {
 padding: 5px 0 10px;
}

.page .right .section .sub.half {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}

.page .right .section .sub h2 {
 color: #676767;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.page .right .section .sub h3 {
 color: #676767;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.page .right .section .sub h4,
.page .left .section p {
 color: #777;
 font-size: 17px;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.page .right .section .sub ul {
 margin-left: 30px;
 color: #777;
 font-size: 17px;
 font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <section class="page">
  <div class="overlay">
   <div id="left_rect"></div>
   <div id="right_rect"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/22/04/00/photo-1103597_1280.png">
   <div class="section about">
    <h1>About Me</h1>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="section contact">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
    <p>
     John Doe<br>
     Some Street 123<br>
     1234 City<br><br>
     <b>T:</b> 01234 5678910<br>
     <b>M:</b> john.doe@mail.com
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
   <div class="top">
    <h1>John Doe</h1>
    <h2>01.01.1990</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="section">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <div class="sub half">
     <h2>School (2,0)</h2>
     <h3>Sep 2000 - Aug 2015</h3>
     <h4>Some School</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="sub half">
     <h2>B.Sc. Business</h2>
     <h3>Sep 2016 - Mar 2019</h3>
     <h4>Some University</h4>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="section">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <div class="sub">
     <h2>Softwaredeveloper at some company</h2>
     <h3>Aug 2015 - Mar 2016</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="dash"></span>
    <div class="sub">
     <h2>Softwaredeveloper at some company</h2>
     <h3>Apr 2016 - Feb 2017</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="dash"></span>
    <div class="sub">
     <h2>Softwaredeveloper at some company</h2>
     <h3>Mar 2017 - Mar 2018</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="section">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <div class="sub half">
     <h2>IT-Knowledge</h2>
     <ul>
      <li>PHP, Java, JavaScript</li>
      <li>HTML, CSS, jQuery, MySQL</li>
      <li>Operating Systems: Windows, MacOS</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sub half">
     <h2>Languages</h2>
     <ul>
      <li>German</li>
      <li>English</li>
      <li>French</li>
      <li>Spanish</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="dash"></span>
    <div class="sub">
     <h2>Interests</h2>
     <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr:</li>
      <ul>
       <li>Sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt</li>
       <li>Sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt</li>
       <li>Sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt</li>
      </ul>
      <li>
       Sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try mpdf,htmltopdf libraries

Comment: Can't you just print to file?

Comment: Yes, if you just need a copy, then why wouldn't you just view in a browser, print and select your PDF writer?

Comment: @RamKesavan indeed.
Use `Mpdf->WriteHTML('<style type="text/css">' . $the_css .'</style>. $the_html));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is working as expected.

For *redability*, html to pdf ignores background images and defaults the text color to system color (which is usually black). **Why?** Because in most cases it does more good than harm. Web graphics can use a wide array of graphic techniques and not all are compatible with print (in the sense it might come out looking bad, being hard to read and it might also be heavier on ink cartridges). Most people printing a web page are interested in the text and its readability, not in the fancy graphics.

So, when trying to Print (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) your CV directly from the SO snippet you placed in your question, by default, Chrome ignored background graphics. After I opened advanced settings and checked *"Background graphics"* it looked as you want it to:

[image]

I have no idea how to enable background graphics in whatever library you're trying to use, but I can assure you most (if not all) have a setting for it that's turned off by default.

All you need to do is find the setting in your library's docs and turn it on.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you are looking a pdf file with CSS. we can do it using xeponlineformatter

please refer below link.

http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf

here you can see a download button, under this button you can save page as pdf.
it will saving your page with appropriate css.

hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with JavaScript/jQuery, but you could try using a software like [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com) which installs you a virtual printer driver, then you print as you would do exactly to a regular printer, just the result will be a PDF file.

If you go for the PHP way, i recommend you [Dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)